# Get user information in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have created a sample in Windows 8 using C# and XAML to get user info of my system which includes Name, Email Id, Photo of my User Login.
I am able to get Name and image but I am not able to get Email Id. My system is logged in by my hotmail id.
Following is  the code: how can I achieve to get email id?

```
string displayName = await UserInformation.GetDisplayNameAsync();
string Emailid = await UserInformation.GetPrincipalNameAsync();
StorageFile image = UserInformation.GetAccountPicture(AccountPictureKind.LargeImage) as StorageFile;
```

In Email id I am getting blank. How to fix it?

Comment: Make sure to check the privacy settings or your account allow that. Also it looks like the GetPrincipalName only works with a domain users.                                      http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getprincipalnameasync

Comment: In my privacy settings i have allowed everything. But still not able to get email id.

Comment: I have tried everything but no sucess I don't know why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@seshuk had given you the correct answer, from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getprincipalnameasync)

> Only domain users have a principal name. Access to the principal name can be blocked 
>   by privacy settings (for example, if the UserInformation::NameAccessAllowed property 
>   is false). If access is blocked, this method returns an empty string.

> This method requires the enterpriseAuthentication capability.

A Hotmail id, by definition, would not be a domain user.  Additionally, you'd need a company account to publish such an app, since it requires the enterprise authentication capability.

Comment: So how will I get the loged in hotmail id for any user??